# Split a string by new line without using inbuilt split function

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I want to make my own function that splits a string with `\n` (new line). I do not want to use any inbuilt function.  How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am not finding a way to  proceed after i detect a   "\n" in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def split_string(string, delimiter):
    output = []
    while delimiter in string:
        index = string.index(delimiter)

        output.append(string[0:index])
        string = string[index+1:]


    output.append(string)
    return output


str = """This is 
a string
of words
delimited
by slash n
ok"""
split_string(str, "\n")
```

op:

```
['This is ', 'a string', 'of words', 'delimited', 'by slash n', 'ok']
```

Comment: This works perfectly! i was not able to achieve the same because i did'nt know about """,thanks for providing me the enlightenment